# unable to build our codename one android projects

Tags: android, codenameone

Since our previous update we are unable to build our codename one android projects, please find attached the logs files of the errors that occur during the server build. Your assistance would be appreciated since we are moving into production.

Error log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NMMXOI0j3CDAYDKBsdHBYSJnlWYq5aMP/view?usp=share_link

Comment: That link is inaccessible and requires permission. If the data is private please use the chat in the Codename One website. If not please provide a gist link or some other way to read that data.